# Why does returning an array here return undefined? (leetcode recursion problem)

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, binary-tree, pass-by-reference

I'm working on leetcode problem 235. Find the lowest common ancestor of a binary tree. I'm using a recursive approach to find a target node. I'm pushing the entire node into an array so I can keep track of my path down the binary tree.

I'm stack at this part where I return the array of nodes and it console logs out undefined. The array logs out correctly if I log it out right above my return statement, but it doesn't log out correctly outside of my inner function. My thought is that i'm having reference issues but I don't know how to go about fixing it.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * function TreeNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.left = this.right = null;
 * }
 */

/**
 * @param {TreeNode} root
 * @param {TreeNode} p
 * @param {TreeNode} q
 * @return {TreeNode}
 */
var lowestCommonAncestor = function(root, p, q) {
    let pAncestors = [];
    let qAncestors = [];
    let lowestAncestor = null;
    
    let findNode = function(currentNode, nodesList, targetNode) {
        nodesList.push(currentNode);
        
        if(currentNode.val === targetNode.val) {
         //console logging nodesList here works

            return nodesList.slice();
        }
        
        if(currentNode.right !== null) {
            findNode(currentNode.right, nodesList, targetNode);
        }
        
        if(currentNode.left !== null) {
            findNode(currentNode.left, nodesList, targetNode);
        }
    }
    
    pAncestors = findNode(root, [], p);
    qAncestors = findNode(root, [], q);
    
    console.log(pAncestors[0]); // this logs out undefined
};
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just need `return` statements on your recursive calls in `findNode`. So `return findNode(currentNode.right, nodesList, targetNode);` and `return findNode(currentNode.left, nodesList, targetNode);`

Comment: @Andrew That would make the left node unreachable whenever the right node is present.

Comment: Not related to the problem: you are  not making use of the fact that the tree is a binary *search* tree. Your solution will not pass the time limit I think.